# Capybara Datalist Select not visible

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<input type="text" id="manufacturer" list="manufacturers" placeholder="Search by manufacturer name or supplier code" class="form-control form-control-2-3" value="" name="manufacturer">


 <datalist id="manufacturers">
     <select>
      <div>
       <option value="Jaguar">AA</option>
       <div></div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <option value="Audi">AB</option>
       <div></div>
      </div>
     <div>
       <option value="Mercedes">AC</option>
       <div></div>
     </div>
     </select>
    </datalist>
```

It's a dropdown menu and I want to select one of the options.  No matter what I try with any find command or select function. I always get the same error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to scope to those options and select one?

Thanks.

Comment: This is pretty interesting problem, your whole datalist is in hidden mode, when I click the text_field, the list is poping up but still selenium is not detecting this list as visible, that's why this error.

Comment: It's a pickle isn't it

Comment: I tried all possible ways, I don't know how to interact with this element, Perhaps this may be possible through activebuilder, but I don't know how!

Comment: Hi, If you don't mine, Can you please add the tag WATIR? people will come on your way to answer your answer perhaps. Can you?

Comment: if you're using Capybara go with the capybara tag, if you're using watir go with the watir tag -- they're mutually exclusive tools adding both tags is just going to confuse people

Comment: @Thomas Walpole are you talking to me? If so, please tag me before you say something otherwise I will not be notified.

Comment: @Rajagopalan No, it was aimed at the OP who took your advice and added a `watir` tag when the question title specifically states Capybara.

Comment: @Thomas Walpole okay, I don't how to handle that so I thought someone from WATIR team must be knowing the solution because WATIR and cabybara both are wrapper around ruby selenium binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't currently possible because it's not actually a dropdown select element. The <datalist> option elements are never actually visible on the page because the standard states "In the rendering, the datalist element represents nothing and it, along with its children, should be hidden." - https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/form-elements.html#the-datalist-element .  Instead any <option> elements in the datalist are just used as autofill suggestions for the input element (but don't actually restrict the value a user can input in any way). Because of this and since the datalist user can just type anything they want into the input element you can set the input value like any other text input.

```
fill_in("manufacturer", with: 'Jaguar')
```

Comment: OK, hopefully this might be something that changes.  Thanks, Tom.

Comment: In the proposed recommendation (as of today) w3c spec for webdriver, it is recognized that dealing with displayedness is especially challenging (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness).
 
That being said, theoretically an option tag as a descendent of a select tag, shouldn't be evaluated as obscured (https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#x11-1-element-interactability). I'm not sure why the presence of `datalist` should make this behavior any different (though obviously it does in this case).

Comment: I tried this example with Firefox (which attempts to be fully w3c compliant), and I couldn't even get it to be displayed correctly in the browser in the first place, to even try with the driver. So, perhaps this should be logged as a Firefox bug and see if Mozilla agrees that this behavior should be changed.

Comment: @titusfortner  A datalist linked to a text input is a completely different beast than a select with nested option elements though.  It really just provides autofill suggestions, a user can't click on the actual option elements.

Comment: To clarify, I upvoted your answer as correct, I was just trying to put out there to the OP that if he wants the underlying behavior changed, he should file a bug because as I read the spec now, it doesn't follow it. It may indeed be desired behavior and the spec itself in need of updating, but that would be useful as well. I've never dealt with datalist before, and Watir doesn't have any specific tests around using it, so this was interesting to explore.

Comment: @titusfortner Which part of the spec do you think isn't followed?  The interesting thing about datalist is that any descendants of a datalist element are only ever user accessible if the browser doesn't support datalist (for instance Safari).

Comment: @Tom FYI - there's a PR  -https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/2021 - that will allow you to use `select` with datalist inputs.  Assuming it doesn't have any unforeseen side-effects it'll probably end up in Capybara 3.1 - you can try it before that from the `datalist` branch.  It ends up just doing a `fill_in` but verifies the option is in the datalist before.